# Google Spreadsheet Script not Updating Dynamically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Ok, I know this has been asked many times, and I know the reason.  Can anyone help me with getting this to Auto update the fields.

Here is pretty much what I am trying to do, just like this guy did.

[Google Spreadsheet Script not Updating Dynamic Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199433/google-spreadsheet-script-not-updating-dynamic-info)

ok, Here is my script I am using.  It calls up the total number of conditionally formatted colors for me.

```
function getColor( sheetrange ) { ////

 var shra = sheetrange.split("!") ;
 if (shra.length==1) shra[1]=shra[0], shra[0]="";  

 var sheetstring = shra[0].replace( /^'(.*)'$/g , "$1") // was: replace( /'/g , "") ; updated 2011-07-17 (ahab)
 var rangestring = shra[1] 

 var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()     
 if ( sheetstring.length==0 ) sheet = source.getSheets()[0] ;
 else sheet = source.getSheetByName( sheetstring ) ;

 return  sheet.getRange( rangestring ).getBackgroundColors()
 }

function rgb( r,g,b , useName) {

  var tmp = "#"+("0"+r.toString(16)).slice(-2)+("0"+g.toString(16)).slice(-2)+("0"+b.toString(16)).slice(-2) 
  if( (useName==null) || useName==true) return tmp=="#000000"?"white":tmp  
 else {  
    var htmlColorNames =  { 
"#f0f8ff":"aliceblue ",
"#faebd7":"antiquewhite ",
"#00ffff":"aqua ",
"#7fffd4":"aquamarine ",
"#f0ffff":"azure ",
"#f5f5dc":"beige ",
"#ffe4c4":"bisque ",
"#000000":"black ",
"#ffebcd":"blanchedalmond ",
"#0000ff":"blue ",
"#8a2be2":"blueviolet ",
"#a52a2a":"brown ",
"#deb887":"burlywood ",
"#5f9ea0":"cadetblue ",
"#7fff00":"chartreuse ",
"#d2691e":"chocolate ",
"#ff7f50":"coral ",
"#6495ed":"cornflowerblue ",
"#fff8dc":"cornsilk ",
"#dc143c":"crimson ",
"#00ffff":"cyan ",
"#00008b":"darkblue ",
"#008b8b":"darkcyan ",
"#b8860b":"darkgoldenrod ",
"#a9a9a9":"darkgray ",
"#a9a9a9":"darkgrey ",
"#006400":"darkgreen ",
"#bdb76b":"darkkhaki ",
"#8b008b":"darkmagenta ",
"#556b2f":"darkolivegreen ",
"#ff8c00":"darkorange ",
"#9932cc":"darkorchid ",
"#8b0000":"darkred ",
"#e9967a":"darksalmon ",
"#8fbc8f":"darkseagreen ",
"#483d8b":"darkslateblue ",
"#2f4f4f":"darkslategray ",
"#2f4f4f":"darkslategrey ",
"#00ced1":"darkturquoise ",
"#9400d3":"darkviolet ",
"#ff1493":"deeppink ",
"#00bfff":"deepskyblue ",
"#696969":"dimgray ",
"#696969":"dimgrey ",
"#1e90ff":"dodgerblue ",
"#b22222":"firebrick ",
"#fffaf0":"floralwhite ",
"#228b22":"forestgreen ",
"#ff00ff":"fuchsia ",
"#dcdcdc":"gainsboro ",
"#f8f8ff":"ghostwhite ",
"#ffd700":"gold ",
"#daa520":"goldenrod ",
"#808080":"gray ",
"#808080":"grey ",
"#008000":"green ",
"#adff2f":"greenyellow ",
"#f0fff0":"honeydew ",
"#ff69b4":"hotpink ",
"#cd5c5c":"indianred  ",
"#4b0082":"indigo  ",
"#fffff0":"ivory ",
"#f0e68c":"khaki ",
"#e6e6fa":"lavender ",
"#fff0f5":"lavenderblush ",
"#7cfc00":"lawngreen ",
"#fffacd":"lemonchiffon ",
"#add8e6":"lightblue ",
"#f08080":"lightcoral ",
"#e0ffff":"lightcyan ",
"#fafad2":"lightgoldenrodyellow ",
"#d3d3d3":"lightgray ",
"#d3d3d3":"lightgrey ",
"#90ee90":"lightgreen ",
"#ffb6c1":"lightpink ",
"#ffa07a":"lightsalmon ",
"#20b2aa":"lightseagreen ",
"#87cefa":"lightskyblue ",
"#778899":"lightslategray ",
"#778899":"lightslategrey ",
"#b0c4de":"lightsteelblue ",
"#ffffe0":"lightyellow ",
"#00ff00":"lime ",
"#32cd32":"limegreen ",
"#faf0e6":"linen ",
"#ff00ff":"magenta ",
"#800000":"maroon ",
"#66cdaa":"mediumaquamarine ",
"#0000cd":"mediumblue ",
"#ba55d3":"mediumorchid ",
"#9370d8":"mediumpurple ",
"#3cb371":"mediumseagreen ",
"#7b68ee":"mediumslateblue ",
"#00fa9a":"mediumspringgreen ",
"#48d1cc":"mediumturquoise ",
"#c71585":"mediumvioletred ",
"#191970":"midnightblue ",
"#f5fffa":"mintcream ",
"#ffe4e1":"mistyrose ",
"#ffe4b5":"moccasin ",
"#ffdead":"navajowhite ",
"#000080":"navy ",
"#fdf5e6":"oldlace ",
"#808000":"olive ",
"#6b8e23":"olivedrab ",
"#ffa500":"orange ",
"#ff4500":"orangered ",
"#da70d6":"orchid ",
"#eee8aa":"palegoldenrod ",
"#98fb98":"palegreen ",
"#afeeee":"paleturquoise ",
"#d87093":"palevioletred ",
"#ffefd5":"papayawhip ",
"#ffdab9":"peachpuff ",
"#cd853f":"peru ",
"#ffc0cb":"pink ",
"#dda0dd":"plum ",
"#b0e0e6":"powderblue ",
"#800080":"purple ",
"#ff0000":"red ",
"#bc8f8f":"rosybrown ",
"#4169e1":"royalblue ",
"#8b4513":"saddlebrown ",
"#fa8072":"salmon ",
"#f4a460":"sandybrown ",
"#2e8b57":"seagreen ",
"#fff5ee":"seashell ",
"#a0522d":"sienna ",
"#c0c0c0":"silver ",
"#87ceeb":"skyblue ",
"#6a5acd":"slateblue ",
"#708090":"slategray ",
"#708090":"slategrey ",
"#fffafa":"snow ",
"#00ff7f":"springgreen ",
"#4682b4":"steelblue ",
"#d2b48c":"tan ",
"#008080":"teal ",
"#d8bfd8":"thistle ",
"#ff6347":"tomato ",
"#40e0d0":"turquoise ",
"#ee82ee":"violet ",
"#f5deb3":"wheat ",
"#ffffff":"white ",
"#f5f5f5":"whitesmoke ",
"#ffff00":"yellow ",
  "#9acd32":"yellowgreen "}
 var name =htmlColorNames[ tmp ]    
 return name?name:tmp
 }

}

function test(){ //
  Browser.msgBox( getColor( "August _11!C3:D3" ) )
}
```

I did try and us googleClock like at this https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/u6dOeAtG0HY/discussion, but it didn't work either. I have also tried on onEdit function but that doesn't work either. All I really want is for this to update like every 60 seconds not a big issue. Everything else works just how I want it.  I will even try another script if it gets this to work.

Is there maybe something in the script that is not working every minute?

Here is link to spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlYQqvtm8-TJdHhKSU10Qk9fay1EelBZd200VEZUMkE&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried adding the GoogleClock() parameter, and it seemed to work fine. For example, in D2:

`=COUNTIF(getColor("Neshig";GoogleClock()),"#00FF00")`

This made it update on the minute.

Comment: Man that was awesome!! I don't know how I missed putting it there.  Its been a long day. Thanks!!!